# Relationship between matrix structure and size of matrix norms

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I am attempting to compute a smallest norm of a matrix (it can be any norm).

Are there any results that allow one to say which norms are smaller for certain classes of matrices (for example, diagonal, tri-diagonal, diagonally dominant, etc.)?

For example, say if the matrix $A$ belongs to the class of matrices $\mathcal{M}_1$, then perhaps we could say that $\|A\|_2$ gives the smallest value out of all other norms, $\|\cdot\|$. On the other hand, another matrix in a different class $B\in\mathcal{M}_2$, then some other norm is the smallest among all norms.

Does anyone know of any such results?

Comment: You need to restrict attention to induced norms for this question to mean much. In that case, the norm of a diagonalizable matrix is the spectral radius regardless of the underlying vector norm. For a nondiagonalizable matrix there exist norms which assign that matrix a norm which is arbitrarily close to (but larger than) the spectral radius. The infimum in this situation is in general not attained.

Comment: @Ian are you sure? let $A = [1,1 ; 1, a]$ with $a>1$. Then, $\|A\|_\infty = 1+a$ which is not the spectral radius of $A$.

Comment: [Spectral radius formula on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius_formula)

Comment: @user251257 See Lemma 5.6.10 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=5I5AYeeh0JUC): For any $n\times $ complex $A$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there is an operator matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$ such that $\rho(A)\leq\|A\|\leq\rho(A)+\epsilon$. I believe that this is what Ian's comment was about; at least its second part. Considering the first part of his comment, it should probably read: for any diagonalizable $A$, there is *an* operator norm such that $\|A\|=\rho(A)$.

Comment: Nevertheless, if $A$ is not diagonalizable, the infimum can still be attained. E.g., $A=\pmatrix{2&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}$ is not diagonalizable, but its spectral norm is $\rho(A)$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel the second part I agree. The first part has made me wonder. But you comment makes sense

Comment: I see that I did make an error: in a norm not proportional to the 2 norm, the eigenvector matrix may not be norm preserving, even when the eigenvectors are taken to be unit and the matrix is symmetric. At any rate, the spectral radius is always the infimum, and is frequently the minimum, over all induced norms.